# What are the performance improvement of Sequential Guid over standard Guid?

Tags: database, primary-key, guid

Has someone ever measured performance of Sequential Guid vs. Standard Guid when used as Primary Keys inside a database?

---

I do not see the need for unique keys to be guessable or not, passing them from a web UI or in some other part seems a bad practice by itself and I do not see, if you have security concerns, how using a guid can improve things (if this is the matter use a real random number generator using the proper crypto functions of the framework).
The other items are covered by my approach, a sequential guid can be generated from code without need for DB access (also if only for Windows) and it's unique in time and space.
And yes, question was posed with the intent of answering it, to give people that have choosen Guids for their PK a way to improve database usage (in my case has allowed the customers to sustain a much higher workload without having to change servers).
It seems that security concerns are a lot, in this case do not use Sequential Guid or, better still, use standard Guid for PK that are passed back and forward from your UI and sequential guid for everything else. As always there is no absolute truth, I've edited also main answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

**GUID vs.Sequential GUID**

A typical pattern it's to use Guid as PK for tables, but, as referred in other discussions (see [Advantages and disadvantages of GUID / UUID database keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45399/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-guid-uuid-database-keys))
there are some performance issues.

This is a typical Guid sequence

f3818d69-2552-40b7-a403-01a6db4552f7
    7ce31615-fafb-42c4-b317-40d21a6a3c60
    94732fc7-768e-4cf2-9107-f0953f6795a5
    
Problems of this kind of data are:<
    -

- Wide distributions of values
- Almost randomically ones
- Index usage is very, very, very bad
- A lot of leaf moving
- Almost every PK need to be at least
  on a non clustered index
- Problem happens both on Oracle and
  SQL Server

A possible solution is using Sequential Guid, that are generated as follows:

    cc6466f7-1066-11dd-acb6-005056c00008
    cc6466f8-1066-11dd-acb6-005056c00008
    cc6466f9-1066-11dd-acb6-005056c00008

How to generate them From C# code:

```
[DllImport("rpcrt4.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int UuidCreateSequential(out Guid guid);

public static Guid SequentialGuid()
{
    const int RPC_S_OK = 0;
    Guid g;
    if (UuidCreateSequential(out g) != RPC_S_OK)
        return Guid.NewGuid();
    else
        return g;
}
```

Benefits

- Better usage of index
- Allow usage of clustered keys (to be
  verified in NLB scenarios)
- Less disk usage
- 20-25% of performance increase at a
  minimum cost

**Real life measurement:**
Scenario:

- Guid stored as UniqueIdentifier
  types on SQL Server
- Guid stored as CHAR(36) on Oracle
- Lot of insert operations, batched
  together in a single transaction
- From 1 to 100s of inserts depending
  on table
- Some tables > 10 millions rows

Laboratory Test – SQL Server

VS2008 test, 10 concurrent users, no think time, benchmark process with 600 inserts in batch for leaf table

*Standard Guid*

Avg. Process duration: **10.5** sec

Avg. Request for second: **54.6**

Avg. Resp. Time: **0.26**

*Sequential Guid*

Avg. Process duration: **4.6** sec

Avg. Request for second: **87.1**

Avg. Resp. Time: **0.12**

*Results on Oracle* (sorry, different tool used for test) 1.327.613 insert on a table with a Guid PK

*Standard Guid*, **0.02** sec. elapsed time for each insert, **2.861** sec. of CPU time, total of **31.049** sec. elapsed

*Sequential Guid*, **0.00** sec. elapsed time for each insert, **1.142** sec. of CPU time, total of **3.667** sec. elapsed

The DB file sequential read wait time passed from **6.4** millions wait events for **62.415** seconds to **1.2** million wait events for **11.063** seconds.

It's important to see that all the sequential guid can be guessed, so it's not a good idea to use them if security is a concern, still using standard guid.
To make it short... if you use Guid as PK use sequential guid every time they are not passed back and forward from a UI, they will speed up operation and do not cost anything to implement.

Comment: With storage engine 'InnoDB', MySQL is storing records by PK in a clustered way, so here you should benefit from Sequential GUIDs as well.

Comment: "It's important to see that all the sequential guid can be guessed, so it's not a good idea to use them if security is a concern" in this case a Comb guid could be used instead which has the benefit of being sequential and random.

Comment: See this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2012/07/03/how-to-generate-sequential-guids-for-sql-server-in-net.aspx   "... results of UuidCreateSequential are not sequential with respect to SQL Server's sort order... To make them sequential SQL Server's internal NEWSEQUENTIALID function performs some byte shuffling on the GUID... you need to perform the same byte shuffling"

Comment: Why is it better is what I don't understand.

Comment: What's the purpose at all of having sequential guids instead of having a sequential integer?

Comment: @entonio you can still generate them in a distributed way (depending on how you go about making them sequential^^)

Answer (score 67):

I may be missing something here (feel free to correct me if I am), but I can see very little benefit in using sequential GUID/UUIDs for primary keys.

The **point** of using GUIDs or UUIDs over autoincrementing integers is:

- They can be created anywhere **without** contacting the database
- They are identifiers that are entirely unique within your application (and in the case of UUIDs, universally unique)
- Given one identifier, there is no way to guess the next or previous (or even *any* other valid identifiers) outside of brute-forcing a *huge* keyspace.

Unfortunately, using your suggestion, you lose *all* those things.

So, yes. You've made GUIDs better. But in the process, you've thrown away almost all of the reasons to use them in the first place.

If you **really** want to improve performance, use a standard autoincrementing integer primary key. That provides all the benefits you described (and more) while being better than a 'sequential guid' in almost every way.

This will most likely get downmodded into oblivion as it doesn't specifically answer your question (which is apparently carefully-crafted so you could answer it yourself immediately), but I feel it's a far more important point to raise.

Comment: Beside the "non guessing" (that I do not consider important, we're not looking to a randomize function) the sequential guid have exactly the characteristic you're looking for, I generate them from C# code and they are unique in time and space.

Comment: sequential UUIDs don't guarantee a global ordering.

They are still universally unique, but they are also locally sequential.

This means that IDs generated on different hosts/processes/threads (depending on the sequential scheme) interleave randomly, but IDs generated in the same environment will be ordered.

Comment: COMB GUIDs are ordered and are very fast for inserts/reads and provide comparable speeds to identity columns. All the percs of an identity column but you don't need to use any crazy replication strategies with a GUID. Identity column you do.  Advantage GUID.

Comment: If it is on the cloud, a standard autoincrementing integer primary key is not good for the long run.

Comment: It is not unique across tables. Cloud is for web scale. Unless your db is very small then it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 23):

As massimogentilini already said, Performance can be improved when using UuidCreateSequential (when generating the guids in code). But a fact seems to be missing: The SQL Server (at least Microsoft SQL 2005 / 2008) uses the same functionality, BUT: the comparison/ordering of Guids differ in .NET and on the SQL Server, which would still cause more IO, because the guids will not be ordered correctly.
In order to generate the guids ordered correctly for sql server (ordering), you have to do the following (see [comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254976(VS.100).aspx) details):

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("rpcrt4.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int UuidCreateSequential(byte[] buffer);

static Guid NewSequentialGuid() {

    byte[] raw = new byte[16];
    if (UuidCreateSequential(raw) != 0)
        throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

    byte[] fix = new byte[16];

    // reverse 0..3
    fix[0x0] = raw[0x3];
    fix[0x1] = raw[0x2];
    fix[0x2] = raw[0x1];
    fix[0x3] = raw[0x0];

    // reverse 4 & 5
    fix[0x4] = raw[0x5];
    fix[0x5] = raw[0x4];

    // reverse 6 & 7
    fix[0x6] = raw[0x7];
    fix[0x7] = raw[0x6];

    // all other are unchanged
    fix[0x8] = raw[0x8];
    fix[0x9] = raw[0x9];
    fix[0xA] = raw[0xA];
    fix[0xB] = raw[0xB];
    fix[0xC] = raw[0xC];
    fix[0xD] = raw[0xD];
    fix[0xE] = raw[0xE];
    fix[0xF] = raw[0xF];

    return new Guid(fix);
}
```

or [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlguid%28VS.71%29.aspx) or [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/03/23/559061.aspx).

Comment: Great point. From what I can get using your code performance could improve some more, sooner or later I'll do some test

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752004/sequential-guid-generator-c and http://developmenttips.blogspot.com/2008/03/generate-sequential-guids-for-sql.html for additional information on this subject.

Answer (score 5):

See This article:
(http://www.shirmanov.com/2010/05/generating-newsequentialid-compatible.html)

Even though MSSql uses this same function to generate NewSequencialIds
(  UuidCreateSequential(out Guid guid)  ), MSSQL reverses the 3rd and 4th byte patterns which does not give you the same result that you would get when using this function in your code. Shirmanov shows how to get the exact same results that MSSQL would create.

Answer (score 5):

I messured difference between Guid (clustered and non clustered), Sequential Guid and int (Identity/autoincrement) using Entity Framework. The Sequential Guid was surprisingly fast compared to the int with identity. [Results and code of the Sequential Guid here](https://www.siepman.nl/blog/id-sequential-guid-comb-vs-int-identity-using-entity-framework).

Comment: Results not found. I would be interested in how you measured the difference. The problem with a standard guids, which are often used, would be page splits on inserts, which would slowly cause query performance to degrade. Did you do the inserts in such a way to cause page splits?

Comment: The URL has updated so you can see the results.

Comment: Thanks. A very interesting analysis. It would be great to do something like that, but then query to see how fragmented each table is. And then compare a query on a highly fragmented Guid table compared with a non unique int table. I'm currently in the process of switching Guids to COMB Guids in the hope that that will speed up query performance.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [COMBs](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25862) by Jimmy Nilsson: a type of GUID where a number of bits have been replaced with a timestamp-like value. This means that the COMBs can be ordered, and when used as a primary key result in less index page splits when inserting new values.

See also: [Is it OK to use a uniqueidentifier (GUID) as a Primary Key?](https://mitchwheat.com/2011/08/02/sql-server-is-it-ok-to-use-a-uniqueidentifier-guid-as-a-primary-key/)

> **Yes**, a uniqueidentifier (GUID) column can be fine as a **Primary Key**, BUT it is **not** a particularly good choice for the **clustered index**. In many cases, you will be better off creating the clustered index on a column (or columns) that are likely be used in range searches, and create a non-clustered index on the GUID column.

Comment: I am a bit skeptical of COMBs and similar techniques, because "GUIDs are globally unique, but substrings of GUIDs aren't": http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/06/27/8659071.aspx

Comment: GUIDs are statistically unique. That is, the chances of a collision is very small. A COMB sacrifices a few bits of the 128 available in a GUID. So yes, the chances of a collision are higher, but still extremely low.

Comment: The whole point with guids is that they have a higher probability of global uniqueness than an integer. That probability does not have to be 100%. While using a COMB guid increases the probability of a collision, it is still many orders of magnitude lower than using an identity column.

Answer (score 4):

If you *need* to use sequential GUIds, SQL Server 2005 can generate them for you with the `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` function.

**However** since the basic usage of GUIds is to generate keys (or alternate keys) that cannot be guessed (for example to avoid people passing guessed keys on GETs), I don't see how applicable they are because they are so easily guessed.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx):

> **Important:**
>   If privacy is a concern, do not use this function. It
>   is possible to guess the value of the
>   next generated GUID and, therefore,
>   access data associated with that GUID.

Comment: I repeat, I do not see Guid used for generate keys that cannot be guesses but as a way to have keys that are unique in time and space and can be easily used for replication, if privacy is important use other approach (real random numbers)

Answer (score 4):

OK, I finally got to this point in design and production myself.

I generate a COMB_GUID where the upper 32 bits are based on the bits 33 through 1 of Unix time in milliseconds. So, there are 93 bits of randomness every 2 milliseconds and the rollover on the upper bits happens every 106 years. The actual physical representation of the COMB_GUID (or type 4 UUID) is a base64 encoded version of the 128 bits, which is a 22 char string.

When inserting in postgres the ratio of speed between a fully random UUID and a COMB _GUID holds as beneficial for the COMB_GUID.
The COMB_GUID is **2X** faster on my hardware over multiple tests, for a one million record test. The records contain the id(22 chars), a string field (110 chars), a double precision, and an INT.

In ElasticSearch, there is NO discernible difference between the two for indexing. I'm still going to use COMB_GUIDS in case content goes to BTREE indexes anywhere in the chain as the content is fed time related, or can be presorted on the id field so that it **IS** time related and partially sequential, it will speed up.

Pretty interesting.
The Java code to make a COMB_GUID is below.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.Base64; //Only avail in Java 8+
import java.util.Date;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer; 

    private ByteBuffer babuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate( (Long.SIZE/8)*2 );
private Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getUrlEncoder();
public  String createId() {
    UUID uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID();
        return uuid2base64( uuid );
}

    public String uuid2base64(UUID uuid){ 

        Date date= new Date();
        int intFor32bits;
        synchronized(this){
        babuffer.putLong(0,uuid.getLeastSignificantBits() );
        babuffer.putLong(8,uuid.getMostSignificantBits() );

                long time=date.getTime();
        time=time >> 1; // makes it every 2 milliseconds
                intFor32bits = (int) time; // rolls over every 106 yers + 1 month from epoch
                babuffer.putInt( 0, intFor32bits);

    }
        //does this cause a memory leak?
        return encoder.encodeToString( babuffer.array() );
    }
```

}