# Switching to sequential (comb) guids - what about existing data?

Tags: sql-server, guid, sequential

We have a database with 500+ tables, in which almost all the tables have a clustered PK that is of datatype guid (uniqueidentifier).

We are in the process of testing a switch from "normal" "random" guids generated through .NETs Guid.NewGuid() method to sequential guids generated through the [NHibernate guid.comb algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665417/sequential-guid-in-linq-to-sql/2187898#2187898). This seems to be working well, but what about clients that already have millions of rows with "random" primary key values?

- Will they benefit from the fact that new ids generated from now on will be sequential?
- Could/should anything be done to their existing data?

Thanks in advance for any pointers on this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, but I'm not sure you would want to. I dont see any benefit in using sequential guids, in fact using guids is not recommended as a primary key unless there are distributed/replication reasons involved. Are you using a clustered index?

Having said that if you go ahead, I recommend loading a table with values from your algorithm first.

You are going to have hassles with foreign keys. You will need to associate the old and new guids in the aformentioned table, drop the foreign keys, perform a transactional update, then reapply the foreign keys.

I dont think it is worth the hassle unless you were moving away from guids altogether to say an integer based system.

Comment: Using a GUID as a primary key has many advantages, its definitely not "not recommended".  Using it as a clustered key is indeed not recommended, as it can lead to bad fragmentation, and it uses a lot of space in every related non-clustered index.

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether the tables are clustered on the primary index or on another index. For instance, if you are creating large amounts of new records in a table with a GUID PK and a creation date, it usually makes sense to cluster by the creation date in order to optimize the insert operation.

On the other hand, depending on the queries done, a cluster on the GUID may be better, in which case using sequential GUIDs can help with the insert performance. I'd say that it isn't possible to give a final answer to your question without in-depth knowledge of the usage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar issue, I think it would be possible to update existing data by writing an application to update your existing keys using the NHibernate guid.comb algorithm. To propogate the new keys to related foreign key tables maybe it would be possible to temporarily cascade updates? Doing this through .NET code would be slower than an SQL script, another option might be to duplicate the guid.comb logic in SQL but not sure if this is possible.

If you choose to retain the existing data, using the guid.comb algorithm should have some performance improvement, there will still be page splitting when inserts occur but because new guids are sequential instead of totally random this will be at least somewhat reduced. Another option to consider would be to remove the clustered index on your GUID primary key, although I'm not sure how much existing query performance will be impacted.