# Are there any known incidents of UUIDs colliding?

Tags: random, probability, uuid, collision

Has anyone ever experienced a UUID collision in the wild?  Anyone heard or read of one happening?  Can you provide any details?

Comment: UUID in iOS ? or in other platform? As a reminder, use of UUID is deprecated in programming starting from iOS 5.

Comment: One thing that may not be related but interesting: Two Windows Phone 7 Apps from two companies will uninstall each other -- if you install one, the other will be uninstalled. The reason is that the developers copied the code about installing and registering the app in the phone from sample code on a book, along with the UUID in the sample.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038023/uuid-collision-risk-using-different-algorithms

Comment: and this one too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703035/when-are-you-truly-forced-to-use-uuid-as-part-of-the-design

Comment: Follow-up: yes in MD5. Also in PRNG. Flutter/Dart resource usage higher on mobile than Micronaut/Java but builds are easy as libGDX/Gradle.