# Entity Framework, seeding and identity

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I need to create some dummy records in the database but when I use the code below to fill the database it doesn't create anything.

I get no errors and I can see that the seed method is running.

I suspect that it has to do with identity and auto increment or something but I'm not quite sure.

I have some recursive tables and relationships going on between tables so how can I handle this in my Seed method?

```
    namespace CalMeser.Data.Sql.Migrations
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;

    using CalMeser.Data.Entities;

    [ContractVerification(false)]
    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DataContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(DataContext context)
        {
            context.Tags.AddOrUpdate(new Tag
                                     {
                                         Name = "Computers", 
                                         Sort = 1, 
                                         Children = new List<Tag>
                                                    {
                                                        new Tag
                                                        {
                                                            Name = "Computer Science", 
                                                            Sort = 1, 
                                                            Children = new List<Tag>
                                                                       {
                                                                           new Tag
                                                                           {
                                                                               Name = "Programming", 
                                                                               Sort = 4
                                                                           }, 
                                                                           new Tag
                                                                           {
                                                                               Name = "Security", 
                                                                               Sort = 2
                                                                           }, 
                                                                           new Tag
                                                                           {
                                                                               Name = "Algorithms", 
                                                                               Sort = 3
                                                                           }, 
                                                                           new Tag
                                                                           {
                                                                               Name = "Data Structures", 
                                                                               Sort = 1
                                                                           }, 
                                                                       }
                                                        }, 
                                                        new Tag
                                                        {
                                                            Name = "Computer Information Systems", 
                                                            Sort = 2
                                                        }, 
                                                        new Tag
                                                        {
                                                            Name = "Computer Engineering", 
                                                            Sort = 3
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                     });

            context.Tags.AddOrUpdate(new Tag
                                     {
                                         Name = "Nature", 
                                         Sort = 1, 
                                         Children = new List<Tag>
                                                    {
                                                        new Tag
                                                        {
                                                            Name = "Animals", 
                                                            Sort = 3, 
                                                            Children = new List<Tag>
                                                                       {
                                                                           new Tag
                                                                           {
                                                                               Name = "Cats", 
                                                                               Sort = 1
                                                                           }, 
                                                                           new Tag
                                                                           {
                                                                               Name = "Dogs", 
                                                                               Sort = 2
                                                                           }, 
                                                                           new Tag
                                                                           {
                                                                               Name = "Fish", 
                                                                               Sort = 3
                                                                           }, 
                                                                           new Tag
                                                                           {
                                                                               Name = "Monkeys", 
                                                                               Sort = 4
                                                                           }, 
                                                                       }
                                                        }, 
                                                        new Tag
                                                        {
                                                            Name = "Plants", 
                                                            Sort = 2, 
                                                            Children = new List<Tag>
                                                                       {
                                                                           new Tag
                                                                           {
                                                                               Name = "Mint", 
                                                                               Sort = 1
                                                                           }, 
                                                                           new Tag
                                                                           {
                                                                               Name = "Sage", 
                                                                               Sort = 2
                                                                           }, 
                                                                           new Tag
                                                                           {
                                                                               Name = "Lime", 
                                                                               Sort = 3
                                                                           }
                                                                       }
                                                        }, 
                                                        new Tag
                                                        {
                                                            Name = "Space", 
                                                            Sort = 1
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                     });

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the entities that are used in the code above.

```
namespace CalMeser.Data.Abstractions
{
    public abstract class Entity : IEntity
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace CalMeser.Data.Abstractions
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public abstract class RecursiveEntity<TEntity> : Entity where TEntity : RecursiveEntity<TEntity>
    {
        public virtual IList<TEntity> Children { get; set; }

        public virtual TEntity Parent { get; set; }

        public long? ParentId { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace CalMeser.Data.Entities
{
    using CalMeser.Data.Abstractions;

    public class Tag : RecursiveEntity<Tag>
    {
        public File Image { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public long Sort { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I decided to ditch auto increment and moved on to Sequential Guid (COMB) so I can precompute the value and initialize it myself.

Here are few articles and posts that helped me to make this decision.

[GUIDs as fast primary keys under multiple databases](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/388157/GUIDs-as-fast-primary-keys-under-multiple-database)

[What are the performance improvement of Sequential Guid over standard Guid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170346/what-are-the-performance-improvement-of-sequential-guid-over-standard-guid)

[ID - Sequential Guid (COMB) Vs. Int Identity, using Entity Framework](http://www.siepman.nl/blog/post/2013/10/28/ID-Sequential-Guid-COMB-Vs-Int-Identity-using-Entity-Framework.aspx)